# Java reference and garbage collector

Tags: java, object

i have two classes below, i want to learn what is the differencies between two type of assignement

**Classes:**

```
 class ClassA {
        public ArrayList<String> listA;
        public ClassA() {}
    }

    class ClassB {
        public ArrayList<String> listB;
        public ClassB() {}
    }
```

I want to put all my values of listB array to listA array, what is the differencies between below usage ? with second usage are there any reference between two classes that can be problem for garbage collector to delete objects.
and what about usage3 ?

```
ClassA clsA= new ClassA();
ClassB clsB= new ClassB();
```

**usage1**

```
for (String s : clsB.listB) {
    clsA.listA.add(s);
}
```

**usage2**

```
clsA.listA=clsB.listB;
```

**usage3**

```
clsA.listA=clsB.listB;
clsB.listB = null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Usage 1: ListA will now have additional elements, those from listB.
- Usage 2: ListA is now ListB, both references refer to the same object (assignment statement). If no current reference for the original ListA then it will be garbage collected.
- Usage 3: ListA is now ListB (reference assignment like before), then right after, ListB is assigned to null (refers to nothing, a null pointer). If there's no current reference for the original ListA then it will be garbage collected.

> I want to put all my values of listB array to listA array, what is the differencies between below usage ?

Usage 1 is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

1. No problem here, really, you just copy the values.
2. You copy reference to the ArrayList. It's OK, just keep in mind that you now have only one ArrayList. Both A and B have the same reference.
3. You basically move the B arraylist to A, and remove it from B. Again no problem.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, option 1 is NOT assignment.  Precede by ClsA.lstB.clear() for copy.

Also, consider 
ClsA.lstA = (ArrayList) ClsB.lstB.clone();

This will provide a clean (shallow) copy of the target.